# What is the smallest ubuntu virtualbox image to run cryptocurrency software on?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, electrum, ubuntu, storage

I'm looking to do all my crypto related stuff like storing coins and managing my coin wallets inside a virtualbox. I plan to use ubuntu as it seems most friendly with many crypto coins. What is the best and smallest image for something like this?

Comment: Do you mean smallest as in the smallest amount of hard drive storage space needed to run a full node? Are you flexible in which bitcoin software you'd like to run, or do you have a specific implementation in mind?

Comment: It could be any coin wallet software. I mean smallest as in OS, not the wallet software.

Comment: So your question could just be boiled down to "What is the smallest ubuntu virtualbox image I can make"? You may get better answers on the [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) stack exchange site.